# Error with Grails Spring Security UI Plugin when creating new user - Error Processing GroovyPageView

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm getting the following error using the Spring Security UI Plugin when I click on the link to create a new user:

```
"Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <s2ui:form>: Error executing tag <s2ui:tabs>: Error executing tag <s2ui:tab>: Error executing tag <s2ui:textFieldRow>: assert beanType | null"
```

I'm running Grails 2.5.5 with SpringSecurityCore 2.0.0 and SpringSecurityUI 1.0-RC3.  I have not customized anything about the plugins.

Everything was working fine for several days.  I'm able to create Roles, I can search for and edit Users.  Everything except the ability to create a new User.  I've spent over 8 hours trying to debug this.

Here's the trace:

```
Line | Method
->>  528 | doFilter  in  /home/mdavis/development/grails/maintenanceManager/target/work/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC3/grails-app/views/user/create.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <s2ui:form>: Error executing tag <s2ui:tabs>: Error executing tag <s2ui:tab>: Error executing tag <s2ui:textFieldRow>: assert beanType
   |
   null
->>   35 | doCall    in /home/mdavis/development/grails/maintenanceManager/target/work/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC3/grails-app/views/user/create.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <s2ui:tabs>: Error executing tag <s2ui:tab>: Error executing tag <s2ui:textFieldRow>: assert beanType
   |
   null
->>   31 | doCall    in /home/mdavis/development/grails/maintenanceManager/target/work/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC3/grails-app/views/user/create.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <s2ui:tab>: Error executing tag <s2ui:textFieldRow>: assert beanType
   |
   null
->>   21 | doCall    in /home/mdavis/development/grails/maintenanceManager/target/work/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC3/grails-app/views/user/create.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <s2ui:textFieldRow>: assert beanType
   |
   null
->>   13 | doCall    in /home/mdavis/development/grails/maintenanceManager/target/work/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC3/grails-app/views/user/create.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by PowerAssertionError: assert beanType
   |
   null
->>  817 | labelCode in SecurityUiTagLib.groovy
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry in advance if this is hard to read, I've never posted anything here before.

Thanks in advance.

Mick

Answer (score 0):

I've come with the same issue, on `grails 3.2`, `org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.0.0.M2`.
This is answered here: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/issues/56
The issue is that spring-security-ui is not handling `null` values of `toString()` properly.
Simply put sth like this on your domain class:

```
String toString(){
    property?: "null property"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late reply: new version of the plugin added these tags below:

```
<s2ui:formContainer type='register' focus='name' width='800px'>
<s2ui:form beanName='command'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem finally figured it out. Your commandBean and and controller might be out of whack.

In your RegisterController.groovy register()
The first lines should on a GET create a empty Command Bean

```
if (!request.post) {
 return [registerCommand: new RegisterCommand()] 
}
```

Your register.gsp validates this on the s2ui:form tag. Make sure the bean names are the same

```
<s2ui:formContainer type='register' focus='username' width='800px'>
   <s2ui:form beanName='registerCommand'>
```